# Comparing SQL tables and getting Values using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have three tables viz: Person(PersonID(INT), Personname(varchar)) , Items(ItemID(INT), Itemname(varchar)) and PersonItemAssoc(PersonItemAssoc(Int), PersonID(INT), ItemID(INT)).

PersonItemAssoc is having many to many association for personid and Itemid.

I want to get way in which if I pass the itemId, I should get all the PersonIds which dont have an association witn this ItemId in the PersonItemAssoc table.

I am using Entity Framework 4.0.
Please suggest a way for implementing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var peopleWithoutItem = from p in Context.Person
                        where !p.PersonItems.Any(pi => pi.Item.ItemId == someItemId);
                        select p;
```

Note that if you get rid of `PersonItemAssoc(int)` and make the `PersonItemAssoc` PK the compound of `PersonID` and `ItemID` then the EF can do People to Items as a many to many, instead of two 1 to many relationships.

Comment: Yes, You are correct, but I have PersonItemAssoc(int) used as FK in other tables, due to which I cant drop that one.